# Is deep the opposite of shallow?

Tags: grammar, antonyms

I came across a text today that suggested that deep is the opposite of shallow but I found this difficult to digest. Furthermore, it feels one could use shallow as the opposite of deep but not vice versa. The word 'shallow' is usually used to quantify depth deriving its meaning from the idea of how *deep* something can be. Deep on the other hand usually signifies *significant* depth but does not necessarily give the impression that something deep is far away enough from shallow that it is an opposite.

From Oxford dictionary:
*shallow (noun)*: an area of the sea, a lake, or a river where the water is **not very deep**.

So in actual sense, it could be more technically correct to say that very deep is the opposite of shallow?

How are cases where dimensions are loosely defined like in this case treated when considering opposites/antonyms?

Comment: You appear to have a shallow understanding of metaphor.

Comment: @HotLicks That was a less than profound statement...

Comment: "Deep" and "shallow" are opposites but they are not absolutes. For example the North Sea is regarded as a shallow sea because it is over a continental shelf but its mean depth is many metres. Conversely a bath containing half a metre of water would be considered deep in contrast to a shallow one which might be only 100mm deep. Also think of a deep cake tin which would be one about 200mm deep at the most: a shallow cake tin would be 25-50mm.

Comment: I see this a lot on ELL - the use of logic to try to convince native speakers that some phrase or definition is incorrect. It’s pedantic at best.

Comment: @FeliniusRex A lot of it is based on the idea that all culture, language, and life is binary...that makes this Q POB.

Comment: @BoldBen So in summary, terms that are not absolutes are still treated without any reference to the dimensions when expressing the opposites. My particularly issue is that I seem to have carried over an impression that deep is *always significantly deep*, i.e. absolute in some way, while shallow is always relative, and there are references to show this is not particular to me.

Comment: You seem to be confusing a definition for the noun "shallows" with that of the adjective "shallow". They have similar meanings but as different parts of speech do not mean exactly the same thing. If you look up "deep" in a dictionary of antonyms, "shallow" is one of the options, so they can be opposites. But "deep" has many meanings, and many connotations, as does "shallow". If you want to know whether deep and shallow are antonyms in a particular context, tell us the context.

Comment: @StuartF I think you have spotted the OP's difficulty. After all The Deep as in the expression "sailing over the briny deep" refers to seas and oceans of significant depth, so deep, in fact, that it would have been impossible to sound  them with a lead line and sailors would have had no interest in sounding them anyway because the depth would have no impact on their ability to sail. The depth of areas of sea caĺled "The Shallows" on the other hand would have been measurable using a leadline, would have been dangerous and the depth, therefore, would have been of interest to sailors.